# Wrong format of a cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I am copying large tables from a website to Excel and it is copied in a wrong format. The number which I need seems to be in a cell but when I click into the cell it shows me that it is a date (and the number shown in the cell is its month and year).

Is it possible to change that so that the number in the cell will be 4.25 instead of 1.4.2025?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not a programming question; see [su]

Comment: May be you can format cell type to text for entire sheet and then paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the format by highlighting the cells, right clicking selecting the *format cells* option.  It will not change the string of numbers from 1.4.2025, but you will be able to replace the date format with something more appropriate for your needs. *

Comment: posting a link to the answer/article will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In the 1900 date system, `1.12` and `12.15` (for example) if entered as `1/12` and `12/15` respectively (where the locale has `.` as the decimal separator) into cells formatted General will show `01-Dec` and `Dec-15` respectively. The underlying number however (ie change format from Custom to Number) is `42339` for both. `42339` in Short Date format shows as `01/12/2015`.

Although generally possible to deduce what malformed number gave rise to what looks like a date it is not always possible to do so. Ambiguity is greatest where the digits for the decimal or integer parts are less than 13. In addition, the locale in which the numbers were entered may play a part (since, in the 1900 date system, `3/4` for example would be interpreted as `42097` where the date convention is DMY 'UK' and `42067` where the date convention is MDY 'US').

So the answer to your question:

> Is it possible to change that so that the number in the cell will be 4.25 instead of 1.4.2025?

is "Yes, but not fully reliably" (and even so would require knowledge or guessing of locale, date system and time of the conversion). Since you are "copying large tables from a website to Excel" it seem you retain access to the source data and I would recommend returning to that. On a small scale manual adjustments may be viable, on a large scale consider importing first to software without such automatic interpretation (eg Word, NotePad++) or, if possible, as character separated values imported as text. Address the delimiters with string handling there and only after that import to Excel or save in Excel format.